# Passing a datetime double that is larger than limited amount

Tags: c#

```
DateTime dt=DateTime.FromOADate(duble); //e.g 3364072679.0
```

My double is unfortunately larger than the allowed range for OleAut Date. What should I do then ?

Comment: If your number is out of range, it's not valid input, and should be ignored

Answer (score 2):

If the fractional (time) part isn't important you could add the remainder to the max OLE date:

```
double maxOLEDate = 2958466.0
int days = duble - maxOLEDate; 
DateTime dt=DateTime.FromOADate(maxOLEDate).AddDays(days);
```

Or just add the value to the "Min" OLE Date:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.FromOADate(0).AddDays((int)duble);
```

**Edit**

I stand corrected - The DateTime structure cannot support OLE date values past 2,958,466.0 (12/31/9999).  Unless [H. G. Wells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Time_Machine) is your user this is not valid input.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [online help for `ToAuthDate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tooadate.aspx), the maximum OLE date is the same as `DateTime.MaxValue` (i.e. the end of the year 9999).

Do you really need to work with dates in the year 10,000 and beyond?